# app(): Argument #2 ($parameters) must be of type array Laravel

Tags: laravel, upgrade

I'm migrating from Laravel 7.1 to Laravel 8, after moving all related file and customizing the way of calling class (cause of differences of Laravel 7 and 8). Migration and seeding are successful, but I got this error when application run after login to admin. This is the error:

```php
app(): Argument #2 ($parameters) must be of type array, Closure given, called in /media/mulyawansentosa/Data/Home Production/Project/Rahaya/hotelbaru/hotel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php on line 149
```

and after lookup to the error pointed, here is content on Pipeline.php on line 149:

```php
...
    if (is_callable($pipe)) {
        //This is line 149
        return $pipe($passable, $stack);
...
```

I really confused how to fix this?

Comment: look through the stacktrace to see if you can see any frames that are not framework code (your code)

Comment: dump $pipe and see what kind of data is this, Pipeline generally receives an array of classes.

Comment: @lagbox all frames show only framework file, there is no my code file.

Comment: @TipuSultanEiko after dd($pipe) the result is:
"app"